# MY SQL: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'libros.editorial' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

El problema es que no veo el fallo en lo que he hecho y no puedo avanzar, ¿Alguna Solucion?

```
select editoriales.editorial, 
       nombre, 
       localidad 
from editoriales, libros 
having editoriales.editorial=libros.editorial 
&& count(titulo)=0;
```

Answer (score 5):

`HAVING` solo trabaja con funciones de agregación por lo cual esa condición que estableces no suena lógica, por lo tanto creo debería ser así

```
WHERE editoriales.editorial=libros.editorial
```

y posterior para hacer el conteo algo así

```
 HAVING COUNT(título) = 0
```

Sin embargo esa sintaxis de `JOIN` no es la recomendada pues me parece no forma parte del estándar; deberías tratar de esta forma:

```
SELECT editoriales.editorial, 
       nombre, 
       localidad,
       COUNT(titulo) AS Total
FROM editoriales
JOIN libros ON editoriales.ediatorial = libros.editorial
GROUP BY editoriales.editorial, 
         nombre, 
         localidad
HAVING Total = 0;
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [CLAUSULA **`HAVING`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: muchas graciass

Answer (score 1):

Deberías revisar la sintaxis de sql pues la sentencia que muestras no tiene pies ni cabeza (I'm sorry).

La sentencia, según la forma más correcta debería quedar así:

```
select editoriales.editorial, nombre, localidad, count(*)
from editoriales
inner join libros on editoriales.editorial=libros.editorial
having count(titulo)=0;
```

Seleccionas los campos deseados, haces un `count` de ellos, unes las tablas con un `join` indicando la relación que tienen entre ellas y luego limitas el resultado de la agregación (el `count`) con el `having`.

Comment: muchas graciassss

Comment: La sintaxis está bien, me suena haberla visto en código viejo, otra cosa es que parece que falta un join